# Data not uploading in my postgresql database of my model (Content)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want to know what I'm doing wrong as my title and body that I specify on rails console are not uploading directly to my postgresql database.

My first Model (`category.rb`) file:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor:name
    has_many :content
end
```

My Second Model (`content.rb`) file:

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :title, :body, :category_id, :author_id
    belongs_to :category
end
```

I've added single post (content) inside this model (Content) using the code below:

```
category = Content.create(:title => "Raikonnen wreaking Havoc",:body => "Raikonnen beats vettel in a thrilling Chinese GP", catagory_id => 2 )
```

The above code does not upload any data and gives command in the screenshot below:
[image: screenshot]

Please help. Please reply if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be when you create your `Content` object, you are missing a `:` in `catagory_id => 2`, so correct your code to include it:

```
category = Content.create(:title => "Raikonnen wreaking Havoc", :body => "Raikonnen beats vettel in a thrilling Chinese GP", :catagory_id => 2)
```

If the problem persists, maybe you have some other validation error, to check for errors try running this in console:

```
category = Content.create!(:title => "Raikonnen wreaking Havoc",:body => "Raikonnen beats vettel in a thrilling Chinese GP", catagory_id => 2 )
```

Notice the **`!`** in **`create!`**. This will raise se an exception where you will be able to see your error.

An alternative would be to first create a `new` object, check if it is `valid?` and get the errors:

```
category = Content.new(:title => "Raikonnen wreaking Havoc",:body => "Raikonnen beats vettel in a thrilling Chinese GP", catagory_id => 2 )
category.valid?
#=> false

category.errors.full_messages
```

Once you get the error, you can either fix the validation or the input data.

---

Not related with current issue, but you have one error with your associations: you need to use plural form of your model when using `has_many`.

So instead of this code:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :name

    has_many :content
end
```

use this code:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor:name
    has_many :contents
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. You've done me a great favor. I'm also not pluralized my Category.rb file. Should I have to pluralize on my Category.rb file?

Comment: category = Content.new(:title => "Raikonnen wreaking Havoc",:body => "Raikonnen beats vettel in a thrilling Chinese GP", catagory_id => 2 )
category.valid?
#=> false

category.errors.full_messages

Comment: After inputting the above command, I get the error "Category must exist".

Comment: What should i do to fix this?

Comment: @madannealcaffrey That error tells you that the id in `category_id` (`2` in your example) must exists in `Category` model (i.e. `categories` table). So first create that category or check which id corresponds to the `Category` you are want to relate your new `Content` to and use that `id` instead.

Comment: @madannealcaffrey And your `category.rb` file should only use plural of `content` because it uses a `has_many` relationship (just as indicated in the answer). But the file name and class should remain singular.